# Integrate Spock with Play 2.6 and sbt 0.13

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, spock, sbt-plugin

I am trying to integrate spock tests with play 2.6 and sbt 0.13, junit seems to run spock tests in intellj IDE, but these tests are not visible to sbt. Digging bit deeper I found that sbt is not picking up groovy files.

I tried using https://github.com/fupelaqu/sbt-groovy plugin but was not able to enable to plugin, looks like it is obsolete.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As a new user please first learn how to write an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then edit your question in order to be an MCVE and dramatically improve the probability of getting a helpful answer. :-)